# Cannot debug android app in Intellij: "Warning: debug info can be unavailable."

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug an app with `Intellij` 13.0 on Windows 7.
Whenever I start debugging I get the following warning:

> Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse"

I have tested it on a device and in the emulator.
The only thing I have open is Intellij. I tried also with closing adb before I start debugging, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you run **monitor** from the Android SDK tools, connect to your device and observe the running applications? If it doesn't work, try reinstalling the SDK.

Answer (score 50):

For me this situation occured when device was connected via usb and `adb tcpip` was enabled (ADB in Wi-Fi mode).

Just run command `adb usb` with connected device and try to debug again.

Comment: Thanks dude. You saved my life. :)

Comment: ADB over wifi has been my favorite way of developing, never thought it could cause such an issue!

Comment: in Feb 2022 this still seems like the best answer. thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Turn the USB Debugging on Device in Developer Options to off.
And then switch it back on.
This solved the issue in my case.

**UPDATE**

One more thing which fixed my case was clearing all existing breakpoints. And then trying to debug again.

Answer (score 14):

I used `adb kill-server` in the console to get the Logcat to appear.  Running Android Studio 1.02.

Answer (score 9):

For those who are using Android-Studio: check your gradle file and product flavours and be sure that "debuggable" attribute in manifest is NOT set to false.

Answer (score 6):

**First** make sure you close any application use ADB , DDMS

like if you open Eclipse with android studio

**Second** restart your ADB from terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

if you cannt find terminal use this image to guide you

[image]

if this doesn't work with you close android studio and open it again

the cause of error , many application share ADB this why you cant start debugging

Comment: adb kill-server
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: try Task Manager -> Process -> adb.exe -> End process

Comment: No. The problem is the adb folder not included at the path environtment variables. So I must add add folder to environtment variables. C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Comment: My alcatel onetouch having issue when I need it to debug app.   :( the same comfig working at lenovo a706.   :(

Answer (score 3):

Had similar problem in Android Studio (0.5.1) with SDK 18.0.1

```
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
```

As you suggested updating the SDK worked. Now running on 19.0 and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You can restart ADB in windows without writing any commands.

Just open **Task Manager**

Sort the list by name

Find process named "adb"
[image]
Right click on it  and then select "End Task"
Done

Next time you run any app the adb will start with a new instance.

Comment: Similarly could be fixed on MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

A pretty straight forward solution is running the following commands in the command Terminal of Android Studio :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and then try debugging again. It should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

The same issues occured with me all of a sudden while debuging an app on my samsung galaxy S6

This is what worked for me : 
closed android studio 
killed adb , using adb kill-server
removed all of my previous breakpoints(debug points)
Restarted android studio and my phone
Restaterted Mac 
did a debug without any breakpoint. 
Then again did debug by putting the breakpoints again in my code, Eureka it worked. Luckily it burned only half hour of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of ADB connections as sometimes ADB cache a dead connection on your real/virtual device and due to which the port is busy and u cannot connect to it.

The simplest solution to this is RESTART your ANDROID phone that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using adb through WiFi? That might cause debugging issues.
If so connect your mobile to your pc thru usb and debug again that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the thing I did was to set

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in `<application>` tag...like:

```
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:largeHeap="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:debuggable="true"
>
```

This fixed the problem with later SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me(If you are connected via USB debugging),

1. Go to the Developer options of the phone
2. Disable USB debugging and all other authorisations for USB debugging.
3. Enable back all

Now try to debug again, hope it will work.